# Make an image appear when a link is clicked

Tags: image, hyperlink

I'm helping with a website for a teacher at my high school, this is for her flower shop page. She wants a list of the months as links and when a link is clicked the 'flower of the month' for that month appears. Should I use javascript or is this easily achieved with CSS? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" value="show image" onclick="showImg()" />
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:40%">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showImg() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I was thinking more like its a link, you click it and a box pops up with the image and then there's an x in the top right to close it